# You have an error in your SQL syntax but query runs in MySQL workbench

Tags: java, mysql, sql, intellij-idea

Query doesn't work in IntelliJ but it does in SQL workbench. On other queries the updatePreparedStatement method works. I've checked my query for syntax errors and strangely enough it does run in sql workbench. Can somebody help a noob out?

```
public void updatePreparedStatement(String queryWithParameters, Object ... values) {
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try(PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(queryWithParameters)) {
        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
            ps.setObject(i+1, values[i]);
        }
        int rs = ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



    public void assignOrdersToDeliveryRoute(BigInteger routeNumber, int[] orderNumbers){
    DbConnection connection = new DbConnection();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(orderNumbers));
    StringBuilder orderNumberString = new StringBuilder();
    int index =1;
    for (int orderNumber : orderNumbers) {
        String order = String.valueOf(orderNumber);
        if (index < orderNumbers.length ){
            orderNumberString.append(order).append(",");
        }
        else {
            orderNumberString.append(order);
        }
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println(orderNumberString);
    String query = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; UPDATE bestelling SET bezorgroutenummer = ? WHERE bestelnummer IN (" + orderNumberString + ")";
    System.out.println(query);
    connection.updatePreparedStatement(query, routeNumber);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work in IntelliJ"? What's the specific error?

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html says:

> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ; characters).

Run your statements one at a time.